# can't pass theme to child components Material-Ui - React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a global theme with shared styles between component, so i don't need to repeat the same classes in each component, so i have a theme file:

```
export default {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#039be5',
      main: '#01579b',
      dark: '#b22a00',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#004d40',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    userNextVariants: true
  },
  form: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  img: {
    maxWidth: 60,
    margin: '1.5rem auto 5px'
  },
  textField: {
    margin: 20
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 16,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 'auto',
    width: 80,
    height: 50
  },
  customError: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '0.7rem'
  },
  small: {
    display: 'block',
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },
  circularProgress: {
    color: '#fff',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
}
```

and in **App.js**

```
import themeFile from './theme';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import {MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeFile);
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <Signin />  
 </MuiThemeProvider>
```

in **Signin** page:

```
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    ...theme
}));
  
const Signin = (props) => {
   const classes = useStyles();
  return //some form and style elements using classes
}
```

But i get an error `TypeError: color.charAt is not a function`, i don't know if i am doing it right, i tried to use `withStyles` but ii got the same error, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the problem is on color in customError. You cannot use 'red' in material ui theme. Try to replace it with #FF0000.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't solve it, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yes and i found a solution for my problem, it is by wrapping anything other than pallete in a new object, i will post the answer so people who will face the problem can solve it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, is by wrapping all properties other than pallette in an object like this

**theme.js**

```
export default {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#039be5',
      main: '#01579b',
      dark: '#b22a00',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#004d40',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    }
  },
  spread: {
     typography: {
    userNextVariants: true
  },
  form: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  img: {
    maxWidth: 60,
    margin: '1.5rem auto 5px'
  },
  textField: {
    margin: 20
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 16,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 'auto',
    width: 90,
    height: 50
  },
  customError: {
    color: '#FF0000',
    fontSize: '0.7rem'
  },
  small: {
    display: 'block',
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },
  circularProgress: {
    color: '#fff',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
  }
}
```

**Signin** page

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   ...theme.spread
}));
```